# iPhone - UIWebview doesn't save authentication to sites

Tags: facebook, ios4, uiwebview, iphone

For these purposes, let say I have an application which contains a single UIWebview.

I'm loading a request to any of these sites: facebook, gmail, twitter, etc., and receive a login screen.

The thing is - that if I log in and relaunch the app, I will have to go through the login screen again.

In Mobile Safari/Google app for example I would retain my login cookie/session details/whatnot and wouldn't need to enter my user credentials again. That is the behavior I want to have.

Stuff I tried:

- sending cookies from the NSHTTPCookieStorage via the NSURLRequest.
- Persisting the cookies myself to NSUserDefaults, but no luck.

How can I achieve the behavior Mobile Safari & Google app has?

Comment: It's definitely possible, as I see now that Google app does it. But how?

Comment: Hi @Gilbert I have been trying to achieve the same result as you specified. You marked the answer below as Accepted. I know how to save  and/or load cookies when application closes/launches but Could you please tell me how do you get Cookies from an NSURLRequest?

Comment: NSURLConnection automatically saves cookies that you receive view NSURLRequest, unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cookies should be archived and persisted when the app is terminated and later reloaded when the app becomes active.  You can achieve this by:

`[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies:cookies forURL:url mainDocumentURL:nil]; // where cookies is the unarchived array of cookies`

Comment: Apparently I messed up the archiving. Thank to you, I triple checked it and it automagically worked.